# Wamp server and xdebug installation

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to install xdebug on wamp server.
With this code:

```
 zend_extension_ts="c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.3-vc9.dll"
 xdebug.default_enable = on
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.remote_host = localhost
```

And apache error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6-nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n   in Unknown on line 0
<br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0  /ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6-nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

I cant see xdebug in phpinfo page. What is wrong :(

Comment: "php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.3-vc9.dll" vs "php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6-nts.dll", which one is it?

Comment: This one:
php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.3-vc9.dll

Comment: And which version of php do you use?

Comment: I see you've tried a "5.2 vc6" and "5.3 vc9". But did you also try a "5.3 vc6" version of the dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you edit the right php.ini?

```
<?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

can tell you.

If (and when) you've edited the correct .ini file are there any php startup errors in the apache log (apache_error.log)?

Comment: Thanks for Help
I have edited the right php.ini.

Error log:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6-nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n   in Unknown on line 0
<br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0  /ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6-nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax used for loading the module is the php 5.2 version. For php5.3 use
zend_extension=module_path/name